# Where can I download odoo 11 addons for enterprise?

Tags: odoo-11, add-on

I am using Odoo.sh,  Odoo 11.0+e (Enterprise Edition) and would like to download the addons. How can I do this?

thankou

Answer (score 0):

If you are an Odoo enterprise partner you can ask your Odoo Account manager to share Odoo enterprise code your Github account.
Once it is linked you can download all enterprise source code from github.